# Is it possible to find which end causes io.Copy failure?

Tags: go, io

In my golang program, I use `io.Copy()` to relay the flow between end1 and end2.

```golang
func relay(src, dst net.Conn, stop chan bool) {
    stop <- (io.Copy(src, dst) == nil)
}
func myprog(e1, e2 net.Conn) {
    stop := make(chan bool)
    go relay(e1, e2, stop)
    go relay(e2, e1, stop)
    result := <-stop
    // Which end causes failure? Or both of them?
}
```

When one of the relay failed, how can I find out which end is closed/dropped. By result? Or call some member function of e1/e2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, making two `relay` sharing a channel and returning an error with no information of which `relay` it is from, obviously is not helping to understanding which endpoint is faulty.

Second, you can wrap Read and Write method of each endpoint to notify the error, like:

```
type errReader struct {
    r   io.Reader
    err error
}

func (er *errReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := er.r.Read(b)
    er.err = err
    return n, err
}

type errWriter struct {
    w   io.Writer
    err error
}

func (ew *errWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := ew.w.Write(b)
    ew.err = err
    return n, err
}
```

Note: The above code takes no consideration of concurrent read or write, nor continuation after error (which may set the err value back to nil again) though it should not be a problem for `io.Copy`. It also does not ignore `io.EOF` error, so you may want to check it explicitly.

Comment: @velkor is right. This is just a simple proof of concept code.